# Downloading XML file instead of rendering using Builder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, builder

I am currently using Builder to make a custom XML export. However when the user clicks the button I want the .xml to download instead of rendering.

I have tried using `send_data` instead of `render` but that seems to be overridden by builder.

Also using ActiveAdmin (hence the `member_action`)

In my controller:

```
  member_action :show do
    @listing = Listing.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.xml 
    end
  end
```

Links to show.xml.builder

```
xml.instruct!
xml.XMLopener { |b|
  b.....
  ......
  ....
  }
```

I have looked at a few links below but I can't seem to get it working. Any ideas?
Obviously with the current code it is just rendering, which works perfectly.

https://www6.software.ibm.com/developerworks/education/x-rubyonrailsxml/x-rubyonrailsxml-a4.pdf
http://danengle.us/2009/05/generating-custom-xml-for-your-rails-app/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something like this

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.xml { send_file :filename => 'mydoc.xml', :type=>"application/xml", :disposition => 'attachment' }
end
```

Comment: Yeah I have and in returns the error:

TypeError at /admin/listings/c8425d8ad3bd71317fccf5bc4e7a490b.xml
can't convert Hash into String