# Rails - Force XML template to be downloaded instead of rendered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml

My question is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18653336/downloading-xml-file-instead-of-rendering-using-builder) but that answer does not work for me. I have a custom xml file that I want downloaded instead of rendered by the browser. I've tried the `send_file` method like [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18653629/1276696) to the question I linked above, but I also get an error `can't convert Hash into String`.

Controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.tmx 
end
```

Template: **show.tmx.erb**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tmx xmlns="http://www.gala-global.org/oscarStandards/tmx/tmx14b.html" version="1.4b">
</tmx>
```

View (I want this link to download a document instead of render in the browser):

```
 <%= link_to "Download", document_path(@document, format: "tmx") %>
```

Comment: What version of Rails and Ruby are you using? Also see: http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionController/DataStreaming/send_data

Comment: I'm using Rails 4.1.6

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the send_file, however it would need to refer to another endpoint already setup supplying the content. Or if you don't use the xml in any other context you can use the following:

```
format.tmx { send_data render_to_string(:show), filename: 'file.tmx', type: 'application/xml', disposition: 'attachment' }
```

HTH,

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for! I made a small edit as there was a missing comma and quotation mark (but SO forces me to edit at least 6 characters so I had to make some superficial edits as well).